# Using dynamic SQL in MySql function

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have created a function in phpMyAdmin as shown in this screenshot[image: screenshot].

When I try to use it like this:

```
Select DMax ("id","customers")
```

I get error #1305 saying that `uTable` does not exist. This is probably some basic syntax issue, as `uTable` in the sql statement is taken literally and not seen as a parameter. So how do I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use parameters to a procedure for column or table names. Instead, you need to prepare a statement using those values and execute that. For example:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE uValue INT(11);
    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT MAX(', uField, ') INTO uValue FROM ', uTable);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    RETURN uValue;
END
```

Note that you cannot use dynamic SQL in a function, so you would need to convert this into a stored procedure with `uValue` an `OUT` parameter i.e.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DMax(
  IN uField VARCHAR(100),
  IN uTable VARCHAR(100),
  OUT uValue <appropriate type>
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE uValue INT(11);
    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT MAX(', uField, ') INTO uValue FROM ', uTable);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

Then you would need to call the procedure, something like

```
CALL DMax('table1', 'column1', @DMax)
```

and you can then

```
SELECT @DMax
```

(yes, this is a monumental pain)

Comment: When I try this, I get error #1336 Dynamic SQL is not allowed in stored function or trigger. Does this mean in general, or only on my server? I am not an administrator.

Comment: @esims Sorry - that is a MySQL limitation. Please see my edit for how you can work around it.